# Setting up mongodb behind nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup mongodb behind nginx, and below is the configuration I used. But I keep getting the following error when I reload nginx. Any help is appreciated.

nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "stream_mondo_backend" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:15

[image]

Comment: try to move `upstream` section to place above `server` section

Comment: (( the same eror:  nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "stream_mondo_backend" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trivial mistype. `stream_monGo_backend` in `upstream` section and `stream_monDo_backend` in `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: thank you very much! and excuse me for my inattention. I am newbie in nginx, and too much new info in my head. So the mistype is occured.